# KeyError python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I keep getting this error called :

```
KeyError: 'width'
```

and I have no idea what to do, I defined what `width` is, but it still doesn't work.

```
width = input("For how many characters do you want to align the table?")
```

then I convert it to an `int`

```
width = int(width)

line = ("|  {:^{width}d}  |  {:^{width}b}  |  {:^{width}o}  |  {:^{width}x}")

print(line.format(1))
```

and when I try to run the programm I get an error.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: `input()` takes string as parameter. For example: `width = input('Enter a number: ')`

Comment: @Heyran.rs I tried to put it into " " but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @LukeNing I am not done with the code yet but it should be a table that show you decimal, binar, oct and hex numbers. And You can change the size of the table with the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `width` needs to be passed as an argument to `format`, which doesn't look for variables in the global scope.
2. You need to pass `1` as an argument for each unlabeled field in the string.

---

```
print(line.format(1, 1, 1, 1, width=width))
```

If you only want to provide `1` once, you need to modify your format string.

```
# The leading 0 tells each specifier to take its value from the first
# positional argument to `format`.
line = "|  {0:^{width}d}  |  {0:^{width}b}  |  {0:^{width}o}  |  {0:^{width}x}"

print(line.format(1, width=width))
```

Comment: If the python version is high enough (=> 3.6) the line could be

`line = f"|  {0:^{width}d}  |  {0:^{width}b}  |  {0:^{width}o}  |  {0:^{width}x}"`

Comment: Not quite; you'd still need to double up the outer braces to avoid those being expanded as well. Define `line = f"|  {{0:^{width}d}} ...`, then you could write `line.format(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It should as below

```
print(line.format(1, 1, 1, 1, width=width))
```